# How to start openvpn without any daemonization and log redirection?

Tags: logs, openvpn, arguments, daemon, administration

I want effectively a debug modus, i.e.

- I do not want openvpn to fork
- I want all output in the stdout/stderr and nothing in various logs.

How can I do that? I could stop forking with a --daemon=0, but I still need to run it in a strace to see what it tries to say to me.

Note, strace says that openvpn still has some messages to me on stdout (many `write(1, "important message")` thingies in output).